# adding item to TreeView when node gets expanded

Tags: javafx

Is there anyway I can add items to a TreeView control just when a node gets expanded?

I'd like to add child items to a tree item when the users expands the parent item.

Answer (score 2):

Use expandedProperty, like in the example below:

```
treeItem.expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                        BooleanProperty bb = (BooleanProperty) observable;
                        TreeItem t = (TreeItem) bb.getBean();
                        _treeItemEventHandler.onTreeItemExpanded(t);
                        // add items to t
                    }
                });
```